# PDFTron mac implementation

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdftron

I am working on implementation of iOS and mac application which displays and edits pdfs.

- Implementation of iOS version is finished using code provided bellow.
- The problem is mac version, which does not contain PTPDFViewCtrl and ToolManager classes needed for displaying and editing of pdfs.

> Anyone having any experience using their equivalent classes for mac implementation or suggested mac implementation?

```
#pragma mark - PDFKit
-(void)initialConfig {

#warning MISSING PDFTRon license key
  // initialize PDFNet
  [PTPDFNet Initialize:@""];

  PTPDFViewCtrl *ctrl = [PTPDFViewCtrl new];
  CGFloat offset = 20;
  ctrl.frame = CGRectMake(0, offset, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - offset);
  [ctrl SetBackgroundColor:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];
  [ctrl SetHighlightFields:YES];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  [self.view addSubview:ctrl];

  // open the PDF document included in the bundle in the PTPDFViewCtrl
  PTPDFDoc *doc = [[PTPDFDoc alloc]initWithFilepath:self.viewModel.getFilePath];
  [ctrl SetDoc:doc];
  self.viewModel.doc = doc;

  [ctrl setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

  // add the toolmanager (used to implement text selection, annotation editing, etc.
  ToolManager *toolManager = [[ToolManager alloc] initWithPDFViewCtrl:ctrl];
  [toolManager changeTool:[PanTool self]];
  ctrl.toolDelegate = toolManager;
}
```

Thank you very much for any help.
Matti

Comment: sir can you help me to build a mac app with pdftron. How to intgrat Pdftron SDK with mac app.

Answer (score 1):

For demonstrative purposes there is a Java SWING sample project included in our PDFNetCMac C/C++ download, but this sample is not maintained, nor supported. It uses PDFView class, and shows some basics of integration. The sample does not support annotating for example.

Similarly, there is a C++ Windows MFC sample, which some customers have used as a guide for integration with cross platform frameworks like Qt.

Another option, is to use PDF WebViewer, which requires moving your user interface into a browser element in your native macOS application, but WebViewer includes a full viewing experience, including form filling and annotating.